# Getting class information from ElementHandle<TypeElement>

Tags: java, templates, netbeans, reflection, wizard

I wanted to create a simple template wizard for NetBeans that would take an existing Java class from current user project and create a new Java class from it. To do so, I need to access field and annotation data from the selected class (Java file).

Now, I used the org.netbeans.api.java.source.ui.TypeElementFinder for finding and selecting the wanted class, but as a result I get an ElementHandle and I don't know what to do with it. How do I get class info from this?

I managed to get a TypeMirror (com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType) using this code snippet:

```
Project project = ...; // from Templates.getProject(WizardDescriptor);
ClasspathInfo ci = ClasspathInfoFactory.infoFor(project, true, true, true);
final ElementHandle<TypeElement> element = TypeElementFinder.find(ci);
FileObject fo = SourceUtils.getFile(element, ci);
JavaSource.forFileObject(fo).runUserActionTask(new Task<CompilationController>() {
    @Override
    public void run(CompilationController p) throws Exception {
        p.toPhase(JavaSource.Phase.RESOLVED);
        TypeElement typeElement = element.resolve(p);
        TypeMirror typeMirror = typeElement.asType();
    }
}, true);
```

But what to do form here? Am I going about this the wrong way altogether?

EDIT:

In, response to francesco foresti's post:

I tried loads of different Reflection/Classloader approaches. I got to a point where a org.netbeans.api.java.classpath.ClassPath instance was created and would contain the wanted Class file, but when I tried loading the said class with a Classloader created from that ClassPath, I would get a ClassNotFoundException. Here's my code:

```
Project project = ...; // from Templates.getProject(WizardDescriptor);
ClasspathInfo ci = ClasspathInfoFactory.infoFor(project, true, true, true);
final ElementHandle<TypeElement> element = TypeElementFinder.find(ci);
FileObject fo = SourceUtils.getFile(element, ci);

ClassPath cp = ci.getClassPath(ClasspathInfo.PathKind.SOURCE);

System.out.println("NAME: " + element.getQualifiedName());
System.out.println("CONTAINS: " + cp.contains(fo));
try {
    Class clazz = Class.forName(element.getQualifiedName(), true, cp.getClassLoader(true));
    System.out.println(clazz.getName());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
}
```

This yields:

```
NAME: hr.test.Test
CONTAINS: true
SEVERE [org.openide.util.Exceptions]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hr.test.Test
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at org.openide.execution.NbClassLoader.findClass(NbClassLoader.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.classpath.ClassLoaderSupport.findClass(ClassLoaderSupport.java:113)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use plain old reflection? E.g.

```
    Class<?> theClazz = Class.forName("com.example.myClass");
    Annotation[] annotations = theClazz.getAnnotations();
    Field[] fields = theClazz.getFields();
    Method[] methods = theClazz.getMethods();
    // from here on, you write a file that happens to be in the classpath,
    // and whose extension is '.java'
```

Comment: I've tried this but with little luck. The problem (I think) is that the Classloader used in the wizard cannot load those classes. Remember, this isn't in runtime (with respect to the selected .java file). The selected file (that the ElementHandle translates to) might not even be compiled. Someone could've just added a new Java Class file to his project and select it in the wizard. It might not even be compilable at that point!

Comment: I've edited my post to give a more extensive explanation of what I tried. Thank you for your help, by the way.

Comment: Oh, I understand. You're right, reflection is not useful in this case. You could take a look at the source code of some project that performs source code analisys (e.g findbugs : https://code.google.com/p/findbugs/source/browse/). While it may not be of immediate help since you want/have to use the Netbeans API (and with good reason), it may give you hints on how it can be done. Sorry for not being more helpful.